# How to increase message size on a network

Tags: networking, omnet++, simulator, veins

I would like to know how to increase the beacon size using the OMNET++ simulator. I saw that it is possible to perform this configuration through the cpacket constructor.

```
cPacket::cPacket    (   const char *    name = NULL,
short   kind = 0,
int64   bitLength = 0    
)
```

My goal is to analyze how beacon size can influence message delivery latency between two nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setBitLength()` or `setByteLength()`. If one want to increase the current size of `cPacket` instance, use `addBitLength()` or `addByteLength()`.